# Using object from GET param as where clause in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, get, sequelize.js

I want to make `GET` request that returns data from Postgres database without specifying in advanced the `where` clause.

```
router.get("/:object_query", async (req, res) => {
        var object_query = req.params.object_query;
        var note = await db.note.findAll({
            where: object_query
        });
        if (!note.length) {
            return res.status(404).send();
        }
        res.send({
            note
        });
    });
```

Call for the request would be something like this:

```
localhost/note/{objectID: "1234"}
```

or

```
localhost/note/{objectID: "1234", otherparam: "abcd"}
```

Idea is that I can from same request query table with different rows.

Is something like this possible without writing request for each different number of params I plan to use for `where` clause, as I had an idea? 
How should it be done, from my tries I got

```
(node:23832) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed.
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.params.object_query` is JSON string, you can use `JSON.parse` function

```
var object_query = JSON.parse(req.params.object_query);
```

and url must be like `localhost/note/{"objectID": 1234, "otherparam": "abcd"}`

Comment: Thank you for help, it worked, i was missing parsing the object

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
  router.get("/:object_query", async (req, res) => {
       var object_query = req.params.object_query;
       db.note.findAll({
            where: JSON.parse(object_query)
       }).then(notes => {
          if (!notes.length) {
              return res.status(404).send();
          }
          res.send({
              notes
          });
       });
   });
```

Make sure that param is a valid JSON.

Comment: Thank you for help, it worked, i was missing parsing the object